# JMeter 4.0 : While recording java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm using JMeter 4.0 software.
I used recording template for the same.
I also set proxy (i.e. localhost) and Port (8888 which is also set in JMeter HTTPS Test Script recorder) in a browser(Internet Explorer).

After that I click on start button in JMeter popup appeared (Certificate). I also install the certificate and import that in a browser.

but facing following issue in browser.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161) at
org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) at
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:278) at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) at
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) at
org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:286) at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:199) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:212) at
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) at
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) at
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684) at
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486) at
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) at
org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:697) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:455) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189) at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:235)
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you provide some more information as to what causes the error? When does it trigger?

Comment: what's your windows version?

Comment: While recording I'm facing above issue. I installed certificate as well as I imported that certificate in Mozilla browser also. still facing the same issue.                                                                                                            Windows Verison : Windows 7 (32 Bit ) OS

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem in [loopback](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2777200/installing-the-microsoft-loopback-adapter-in-windows-8-and-windows-ser) (localhost) for Windows 8 users that need to install a new Adapter:

> The Microsoft Loopback Adapter was renamed in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012. The new name is "Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter".
>
> **Resolution**
>
> When using the Add Hardware Wizard to manually add a network adapter, choose Manufacturer "Microsoft" and choose network adapter "Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter".

You can try to record using [firefox guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios) if this doesn't help you.